# component syntax in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm a beginner in React, just some questions about component
Let's say I have a component :

```
function HelloWorld() {
    return React.createElement('div', {}, 'Hello World!')
}
```

so my questions are:

1- HelloWorld is the component name, isn't it?

2- then I have the code below:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <HelloWorld/>, document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

what's the syntax of `<ComponentName/>`? isn't that more sensible to have the render function to be like:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    HelloWorld(), document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Comment: [JSX is compiled to `React.createElement` calls](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwCQpgNhD2Dq0CcIBMD0A-IA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.2.2). You don't have to use it if you don't want to.

Comment: Check the doc of react to see what's the 3rd argument is corresponding to. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

syntax of `ReactDOM.render` this :

```
ReactDOM.render( <Component />, id of DOM element where component will render );
```

in React there are 2 types of components :

- 1) functional components (also called stateless components)
- 2) class components (also called as stateful components

example of functional component :

```
function HelloWorld() {
    return React.createElement('div', {}, 'Hello World!')
}

or 

const HelloWorld=()=>{
    return (<div>HelloWorld</div>);
}
export default HelloWorld;
```

example of class component :

```
class HelloWorld extends React.Component{
   render(){
      return (<div>HelloWorld</div>);
   }
}
```

so passing component like this :

```
ReactDOM.render(
    HelloWorld(), document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

is not correct way , in React you use Component as `<ComponentName />`

so thats why you have to pass like this :

```
ReactDOM.render(
        <HelloWorld/>, document.querySelector('#root')
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - No, that would be the contents (aka "children") of the `div` tag you are creating. That is `<div>Hello World!</div>`.

2 - Not sure what the `ComponentName` you are referring to is. The snippet takes the `HelloWorld` React component and mounts it to the DOM, which also starts the [Reconciliation process](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html).

Also, the purpose of JSX is to have a syntactic sugar that resembles HTML as much as possible. Yes, what you are suggesting is basically what happens behind the scenes (from a pseudo-code point of view), but would defeat the purpose of using JSX.

Comment: but what does the syntax of <.../> mean?

Comment: You should read the basics of React in their doc : https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Answer (score 0):

When react builds your app and run, it will be something like the last example that you gave.

React compile all components to

```
React.createElement('htmlTag' || someOtherComponent(), ...);
```

So a lot of people find more easy and productive to write your components using the JSX sintax and just use the build command to compile and bundle the code.